# how to parse this json [Blogger] to android

Tags: android, json, blogger

I am having problem to parse this blogger JSON file to android
[blogger JSON structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bruIc.png)

I want to display title in a string variable please help me

I tried this code

```
@Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            //------------------>>
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONObject("feed").getJSONArray("entry");

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Actors actor = new Actors();

                    actor.setName(object.getString("title"));



                    actorsList.add(actor);
                }
                return true;
            }

            //------------------>>

        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I have to parse the above nested JSON array's data into my application. I am confused how to get the values out of it.

Comment: this is really not a big problem to post it here. The problem is that you missed your root json object "feed", so you need to get your array like jsono.getJsonObject("feed").getJsonArray("entry")

Comment: it is correct, but its not working.. after parsing this the entry array.. then the for loop works, but inside that again curly bracked title appears,,, then its having two objects type and $t ..... whats this..?

Comment: [this is the structure please show how to loop to get the title](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/84304510/json.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`entry` is not in the root object but in the `feed` object so use

```
//...
JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONObject("feed").getJSONArray("entry");
//...
```

Comment: it is correct, but its not working.. after parsing this the entry array.. then the for loop works, but inside that again curly bracked title appears,,, then its having two objects type and $t ..... whats this..?

Comment: Ha...Can you provide more details (logs, `data` value,...) ?

Comment: [this is the structure please show how to loop to get the title](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/84304510/json.png)

Comment: So can you give us the exception ? with the stacktrace

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
     
      Actors actor = new Actors();
      
      actor.setName(object.getString("title"));


      
      actorsList.add(actor);
     }

Comment: unable to fetch data from server